# Arrowhead line pattern

Tags: svg

I'd like to create line patterns like these to indicate direction:

```
> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > >
▶︎ ▶︎ ▶︎ ▶︎ ▶︎ ▶︎ ▶︎ ▶︎ ▶︎ ▶︎ ▶︎ ▶︎ ▶︎ ▶︎ ▶︎ ▶︎ ▶︎ ▶︎ ▶︎ ▶︎
→ → → → → → → → → → → → → → → → → → → →
```

And with the patterns following the lines if the lines change direction. Is this possible within SVG using just styles? See below code snippet but imagine triangles or angles instead of the dashes.

```html
<svg width="200" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80" stroke="black" stroke-width="1ex" stroke-dasharray="8 12" fill="transparent">
        <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="20" to="0" begin="0s" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </path>
</svg>
```

While the animation does convey direction, it would be better to show direction with a shape, with or without animation. For example, for use in static screenshots or presentations, or in older browsers which don't support animation. At some scalings, the user may only see the middle of a line. The end points may not be visible, so he'll need some cues as to direction.

Comment: Your question is a little light on details.  Can you provide more detail about your specific use case, and maybe show us your coding attempt?

Comment: @RobertHarvey – Code sample added. Delay was because couldn't get SVG animation to work within SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using text on a path. The text is a long string of `>`. I'm animating the `startOffset`

```html
<svg width="200" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="path" d="M10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80" stroke="black" fill="transparent"></path>

  <text stroke="#000000" font-size="14" dominant-baseline="middle">
      <textPath xlink:href="#path" startOffset="-100%">
       <animate attributeName="startOffset" from="-100%" to="0" begin="0s" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"/> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
      </textPath>
  </text>  
  
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this with SVG, use the `<defs>` tag to define a triangle and then repeat a list of triangles along an axis. After that you can style and transform it using just css.

```css
.myPoly {
  fill:red;

}

.line {
  transform: rotate(110deg);
  transform-origin:5px 70px;
}
```

```html
<svg height="210" width="500">
  <defs>
    <polygon id="myPoly" class="myPoly" points="5,2 9,12 1,12" 
   
  />
  </defs>
  <g class="line">
    <use x="0" y= "0" xlink:href = "#myPoly"/>
    <use x="0" y="10" xlink:href = "#myPoly"/>
    <use x="0" y="20" xlink:href = "#myPoly"/>
    <use x="0" y="30" xlink:href = "#myPoly"/>
    <use x="0" y="40" xlink:href = "#myPoly"/>
    <use x="0" y="50" xlink:href = "#myPoly"/>
    <use x="0" y="60" xlink:href = "#myPoly"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```